# Generate new ethereum address

Tags: ethereum

I'm currently working on a ethereum dapp where users can login and perform transactions. I'm a newbie in dapp development. The problem is I've been trying to make something happen which is when a user registers the dapp, a wallet address will automatically be generated for that user. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Try being more specific. Is this a mobile app, web app, or a fat client? Do you have restrictions which require you to use a light node? It's a little hard to address your question without details and without outlining what you've tried, where you're stuck, and without any code. Have you already looked at Geth or Parity?

Comment: What I want is actually a script to automatically generate new accounts for users immediately they sign up into my web app.

Comment: You can check out [ethereumjs-wallet](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An account on Ethereum is nothing but holding a private key.

There are many software packages like web3j (for java), web3js (for javascript) which help in creating private keys and accounts.

To create a private key, you need to input a string. This string will be sent to a one-way hash function. Since private keys have to be unique for every account, the input string has to be random. Few standard practices would be using the (current time stamp + user mail id + password + random phrases) as the input string.

Once you create a private key for a user, you can generate an account for him.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing your own code or are you looking for a  plug-and-produce code snippet? On a very general level, you will have to code a three-step algorithm:

1. Generate a private key using some degree of randomization. Along the lines of bitaddress.org or similar services.
2. Generate a public key from your private key using ECC (specifically the secp256k1 curve, which is a good fit for Ethereum).
3. Create a public address out of the public key, which might also consist of generating a compressed public address, then refining this address, etc

I saw a good explanation in [this article](https://yad.finance/blog/wallet-off-the-wall/). I guess, they want you to learn interactively. You generate the keys yourself. Step by step. As a learning experience.  Until they key pair is created and imported into your wallet client.